Python packages: Multiple subprojects
I have this directory structure:
pyproject.toml
proj1/
  pyproject.toml
  MANIFEST.in
  proj1/
    __init__.py
proj2/
  pyproject.toml
  MANIFEST.in
  proj2/
    __init__.py

What I want to do is:

The toplevel pyproject.toml is only there for e.g. formatting and including proj1 and proj2
proj1 and proj2 are packages that should be packaged.
I want that if I do e.g. python -m build (Or hatch build, I don't care what buildsystem, as long as it works and is somewhat well-known) in the toplevel directory, that *.whl and *.tar.gz files are generated in a toplevel dist/ - for every subproject.

Is that possible?
My toplevel pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "projs"
version = "0.0.3"
description = ""

[tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel]
packages=["proj1", "proj2"]
[tool.hatch.build.targets.sdist]
packages=["proj1", "proj2"]

my proj1 (and proj2)/pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "proj1"
license = "AGPL-3.0-or-later"



[tool.hatch.version]
path = "proj1/__init__.py"

[tool.hatch.build.targets.sdist]
include = [
    "/proj1",
]

But now, if I run hatch build, I get only the toplevel dist/projs-$VERSION.tar.gz containing paths I don't want to have. (E.g. projs-$VERSION/proj1/proj1/__init__.py) Is this doable with any packaging technology of python?

Anything wrong with doing this in a (bash) for loop? for proj in path/to/projs/*; do (cd $proj; hatch build; cp build/* ../build); done;. Or something like that. You lose the top level pyproject. But there are ways to get common formatting options a different way.

It's not that elegant and feels hacky having to shell out to a shell

But @Dunes can you tell me what the idiomatic way to share common formatting options etc. (For djlint, black, isort, etc.)

Black does what you want already. It keeps looking up parent directories until it finds a pyproject.toml that contains black options, or the repository, root or the file system root. Looks like isort will do the same. djlint isn't particularly clear on the subject. Maybe it's better to just try and see what happens.

My initial solution was to use side config files eg (.isort.cfg), store the main in the repo root and then symlink to it in the child projects.
